# How do I set my checkbox checked by default after a certain action is performed?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, default

I have an activity with a list of checkboxes. A checkbox and after clicking it, the next action is called, performed, and completed. Afterward, the action is completed, the app returns to the action with a list of checkboxes and now I want the used checkbox to be checked by default and unable to be clicked again. Please help!

This is what I tried to do but was not successful checkbox becomes unchecked when I return to the action:

```
P2106.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                Intent move = new Intent(GeneralRoute.this, ScanTest.class);
                startActivity(move);
                P2106.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: you can store that data in `sharedPreferences` or you can use a database ie: Firebase to store that then you can check wheater the user is checked or not.

Comment: Make your list static, or use a shared preferences or database to save your data, if you want an easy way, you must make your list static and in your setOnCheckedChangeListener you have to change a value of your model

Comment: @OneDev how do I do it? Could you show me an example code, please?

Comment: Yes, I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your model class

```
public class YourModel {

private boolean someBoolean;
private String someString;
private int someInt;

public boolean isSomeBoolean() {
    return someBoolean;
}

public void setSomeBoolean(boolean someBoolean) {
    this.someBoolean = someBoolean;
}

public String getSomeString() {
    return someString;
}

public void setSomeString(String someString) {
    this.someString = someString;
}

public int getSomeInt() {
    return someInt;
}

public void setSomeInt(int someInt) {
    this.someInt = someInt;
}
}
```

your activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static ArrayList<YourModel> modelList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Add Your Model Or Data To ArrayList
    modelList.add(new YourModel());
    modelList.add(new YourModel());

    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.youtListView);
    YourAdapter yourAdapter = new YourAdapter(this, R.id.youtLayoutListItem, modelList);
    listView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);


}
}
```

and your adapter

```
public class YourAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<YourModel> {

private ArrayList<YourModel> modelList;

public YourAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<YourModel> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.modelList = (ArrayList<YourModel>) objects;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return modelList.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public YourModel getItem(int position) {
    return modelList.get(position);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
            ...
    }
    YourModel model = modelList.get(position);
    P2106.setChecked(model.isSomeBoolean());
    P2106.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                Intent move = new Intent(GeneralRoute.this, ScanTest.class);
                startActivity(move);
                P2106.setChecked(true);
                model.setSomeBoolean(true);
                modelList.set(modelList.indexOf(model), model);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
}
```

**Don't Forget to replace with your data**